# Error about using AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, avplayerviewcontroller, avqueueplayer, avplayeritem

I init a AVQueuePlayer like :

```
AVPlayerItem *item1 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX.mp4"]];
AVPlayerItem *item2 = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://YYY.mp4"]];
AVQueuePlayer player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]initWithItems:@[item1,item2]];
```

and I want to show it by AVPlayerViewController so I init a AVPlayerViewController like :

```
AVPlayerViewController  *playerController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
playerController.player = player;

...

...

[self.view addSubview:_playerController.view];
[self addChildViewController:_playerController];
```

now I want to play it:

```
[player play];
```

**Question:
It always crashes at main when the first AVPlayerItem end play.
Did I do something wrong or wrong way to show it?
(AVPlayer is OK by this way)**

Comment: AVQueuePlayer player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]initWithItems:@[item1,item2]]; your problem is here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I missed * when I ask the question. in the code it is            AVQueuePlayer* player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]initWithItems:@[......

Comment: hope you did solve your problem now.

Comment: thank you. but it still not work ....

Comment: Try with single item and in next button item change your player item and check it

Comment: But that's just what AVPlayer's job.  I wanna AVQueuePlayer instead.I'll keep trying.thanks for your advice.

Comment: then use Notificationcenter and add notification when you set up your player and in notification just write simple code for play next video and its playing continue